# Как убрать выборки с повторяющимися элементами

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, как реализовать такую штуку?.

```
while($ser_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
    $serviceid = $ser_row['serviceid'];
    $servicename = $ser_row['servicename'];
    $autouserid = $ser_row['autouserid'];
    $carnomer = $ser_row['serialnumber'];
    $avtograf = $ser_row['avtograf'];
    $rastoplivo = $ser_row['rastoplivo'];
    $allmkad = $ser_row['allmkad'];
    $peregruztn = $ser_row['peregruztn'];
```

С начало нужно убрать все повторения из $ser_row['serialnumber'];  а потом найти по ним все $ser_row['allmkad']; и сложить их.

Comment: чего бы не сделать 

     service[$ser_row['serialnumber']]=$ser_row; 

а потом пройтсь foreach по массиву service ?

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажешь как(foreach)? А то у меня хрень какая то выходит.. в запросе не подходит там свой поиск и вывод в табличку а сложить все нужно для итога.

Comment: что непонятного ?

$sum=0;
foreach($service as $ser) $sum+=(int)$ser['allmkad'];
echo $sum;

Comment: Эмм так он складывает общую сумму по всем serialnumber. Дело в том что мне нужно что бы он считал общий итог по каждой из serialnumber

Comment: Дядь Спасибо за help ) все вышло прям как я хотел!

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно отсеять повторения строк и произвести операцию над значениями остальных, это лучше сделать в sql при помощи GROUP BY. [ЖМИ](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит так как нужно с начало вытащить всё в таблицу а потом уже посчитать итоги

Comment: Уточню @qpaycm

SELECT serviceid, servicename, autouserid, serialnumber, avtograf, rastoplivo,
peregruztn, SUMM(allmkad) as sumallmkad FROM `tablename` GROUP BY serviceid;


В результате все данные будут на месте, а сумма всех allmkad будет здесь - $ser_row['sumallmkad'];

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы "автоматизировать" процесс объявления переменных, то лучше использовать такую строку
    foreach ($ser_row as $key => $value) $$key = $value;

Answer (score 0):

Просто в вашем цикле с fetch

```
$summs[$set_row['serialnumber']]+=(int)$ser_row['allmkad'];
```

или так (если остальные данные нужны)

```
if (!isset($all[$set_row['serialnumber'])) $all[$set_row['serialnumber']=array();
$all[$set_row['serialnumber']]['summs']+=(int)$ser_row['allmkad'];
$all[$set_row['serialnumber']]['rows'][]=$ser_row;
```

Comment: Подскажи возможно ли с foreach сделать так что бы он показывал сначала итог а потом перечислял из чего он получился например по каким датам. 

if (!isset($all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]))
  $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]= array();
   $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['summs']+=(int)$ser_row['allmkad'];
$all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dates']=$ser_row['cf_672'];

foreach($all as $key => $ser) {
  if ($key == ''){
   } else {
$chartauto .= "{ state: '$key', km: $ser[summs], peregruz: $ser[peregruz], prostoy: $ser[prostoy]},";